# andengine tilemap respawn

Tags: android, andengine, tmx

i'm starting to developt a android game using AndEngine gles2, it's a really good game engine and i found a lots of example of how use it. My game is a kind of RPG traditional game using tiled maps, sprite, etc.: my issue is how i can set a mounster respawn area(like the long grass areas on pokemon games) i read a lots of tile map example but in no one appears examples about this, i using a tiled map editor and there i can set properties to the layers and especify there if is a mounster respawn area or not, if can someone tell me how can i do this i will appreaciate so much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the tilemapeditor found here:

http://www.mapeditor.org/

(note, you need to save it with the correct compression type or otherwise andengine will not parse it correctly, cant remember which one I got working but it takes a few minutes to try out).

Then you can rightclick on a specific tile and add properties to it such as:
IsMonsterSpawnArea value = true

Then you can check for "collision" with

```
if(pTMXTileProperties.containsTMXProperty("IsMonsterSpawnArea ", "true")) {
    // SPAWN BIG UGLY MONSTER(or initiate fight!)
}
```

Check out the andengine TMX examples found in the andengine source, they can really help you get started.

Comment: yes, i'm using that editor, my question is if exist a some kind of function in the tmx extension that generate a battle scene when the collision happens, if there no exist a function like those maybe  someone have a example or orientation of how create the battle scene

Comment: I am still not fully following you. Do you want a complete new map to load, why not just load on on collission with the specifik tile?

Comment: that's my problem i don't know how set the collision with a tile where no exist a physical body, like rectangles or circles bodys from the 2d  physics box, but that type of objects i don't know if can walk over them.

Comment: Then I suggest you look at the TMX tile example in the andengine source. There you will find a collision test on each tile the player walks on, and it creates a rectangle below the player indicating the colliding tile. It is very simple once you see it. If you are still having problems I can post you some code in the evening. Dont have the source for my game with me.

Comment: the problem is that how i can walk over the rectangles, in the tmx tile example i se how create de collision but when i create the respawn area it gets filled by rectangle object that don't let my walk over de rectangles, do you know how i can make that my character walk over the rectangles?

Comment: if(group.getTMXObjectGroupProperties().containsTMXProperty("IsMonsterSpawnArea", "true")){
for(final TMXObject object : group.getTMXObjects()) {
final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(object.getX(), object.getY(),object.getWidth(), object.getHeight());
rect.setVisible(false);
final FixtureDef boxFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.0f, 0, 0f);
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, rect, BodyType.StaticBody, boxFixtureDef);
mScene.attachChild(rect);
}